# UEFI boot and data disk

Tags: boot, windows-10, uefi, mbr, gpt

I'm on Windows 10 and I'm ready to convert to UEFI boot, but I want to know, if I need to have all my disks with GPT or only disk from which I will boot. 
Because my data disk is really full and impossible to convert to GPT for now.

Comment: Note that there are tools that will convert from MBR to GPT without data loss. (Assuming no bugs, power failures at exactly the wrong time, etc.) Thus, you *could* convert your data disks from MBR to GPT in a fraction of a second (program operation time; longer for you to figure out how to do it, type commands, etc.). My own [GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) is one program that will do this. I've heard some GUI Windows tools will do it, too, but I don't recall the details. Such tools can be part of a BIOS-to-EFI boot-mode conversion, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 (and older) will happily recognise existing disks with the MBR partitioning scheme. You can use a GPT disk to boot from and data disks, external drivers, pendrives and whatever else I forgot to mention with MBR's on them and they will just work.